# Google vision API Barcode Scanner remove camera view

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, google-vision

Currently I am developing a bar code reader android app with Google vision API. I need to start camera preview when button is clicked and until the button is clicked screen should be empty white color screen. When I Try to do this camera preview starts at the same time screen also appears how to solve this problem please help me.

[image: Screen before Start scanner]

[image: Screen After start Scanner]

My MainActivity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BarcodeRetriever {

// use a compound button so either checkbox or switch widgets work.


private static final String TAG = "BarcodeMain";


BarcodeCapture barcodeCapture;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    barcodeCapture = (BarcodeCapture) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(barcode);
    barcodeCapture.setRetrieval(this);


    findViewById(R.id.refresh).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            barcodeCapture.setShowDrawRect(true)
                    .setSupportMultipleScan(false)
                    .setTouchAsCallback(true)
                    .shouldAutoFocus(true)
                    .setShowFlash(true)
                    .setBarcodeFormat(Barcode.ALL_FORMATS)
                    .setCameraFacing(false ? CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT : CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                    .setShouldShowText(true);

            barcodeCapture.resume();
            barcodeCapture.refresh(true);
        }
    });

}


@Override
public void onRetrieved(final Barcode barcode) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Barcode read: " + barcode.displayValue);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setTitle("code retrieved")
                    .setMessage(barcode.displayValue);
            builder.show();
        }
    });
    barcodeCapture.stopScanning();


}

@Override
public void onRetrievedMultiple(final Barcode closetToClick, final List<BarcodeGraphic> barcodeGraphics) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String message = "Code selected : " + closetToClick.displayValue + "\n\nother " +
                    "codes in frame include : \n";
            for (int index = 0; index < barcodeGraphics.size(); index++) {
                Barcode barcode = barcodeGraphics.get(index).getBarcode();
                message += (index + 1) + ". " + barcode.displayValue + "\n";
            }
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setTitle("code retrieved")
                    .setMessage(message);
            builder.show();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onBitmapScanned(SparseArray<Barcode> sparseArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sparseArray.size(); i++) {
        Barcode barcode = sparseArray.valueAt(i);
        Log.e("value", barcode.displayValue);
    }

}

@Override
public void onRetrievedFailed(String reason) {

}

@Override
public void onPermissionRequestDenied() {

}
```

}

My activity_main.xml file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/actions"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/barcode"
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.BarcodeCapture"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            app:gvb_auto_focus="true"
            app:gvb_code_format="code_39|aztec"
            app:gvb_flash="false"
            app:gvb_rect_colors="@array/rect_color" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/actions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/refresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_layout_for_start_scan">

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your main activity code of both xml and java

Comment: Just separate button logic and scanning into two distinct activities: MainActivity should contain button and on click it should start scanning activity. You can then return result to former one or continue with other flow.

Comment: @3mpty In my case I need to implement both camera Preview and Start button in same screen that is why I am in trouble

Comment: when the button is clicked make visibility to gone when it is clicked.

Comment: use frame layout instead of relative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after few days I found a solution for this :)

To do this you have to edit BarcodeCapture.java class which provide by google vision sample. Please edit it like bellow.

add these Two line into onCreate method of  BarcodeCapture.java

```
   mPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   mGraphicOverlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and Comment `startCameraSource();` line in the `onResume()` method of BarcodeCapture.java

finally add these into `refresh` method in BarcodeCapture.java class

```
   mPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   mGraphicOverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   startCameraSource();
```

Comment: @Umang check this out. thank you again for your continuous support.

Comment: Hey, That's great. :) Congratulations. You're very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I've changed some parts of the xml file: Please try this.

Replace your entire XML with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/barcode"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.BarcodeCapture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    app:gvb_auto_focus="true"
    app:gvb_code_format="code_39|aztec"
    app:gvb_flash="false"
    app:gvb_rect_colors="@array/rect_color"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/barcode"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/barcode" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Press Start Button To Activate The Scanner"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

After changing:

```
findViewById(R.id.refresh).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        RelativeLayout rel = findViewById(R.id.relative);
        rel.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        barcodeCapture.setShowDrawRect(true)
                .setSupportMultipleScan(false)
                .setTouchAsCallback(true)
                .shouldAutoFocus(true)
                .setShowFlash(true)
                .setBarcodeFormat(Barcode.ALL_FORMATS)
                .setCameraFacing(false ? CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT : CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                .setShouldShowText(true);

        barcodeCapture.resume();
        barcodeCapture.refresh(true);
    }
});
```

Before the above change, write this:

```
barcodeCapture.setShowDrawRect(false);
```

Try it.. and let me know if it works fine

Comment: this is not a solution for my problem

Comment: Mr. Dulanga, did you try before making a comment.. I tried it in my system myself.

Comment: yes I tried it, I need do remove the camera preview binning of the screen (before click the button) Please check my two screen shorts.  camera preview should appear only after button click.

Comment: So you need the white screen first then Camera view?

Comment: Yes, First white screen after button click camera preview should start

Comment: @Dulanga Check my edited answer and see if it is working now.

Comment: This time your solution working fine but I have some doubt about your solution because your add and remove layout on top off camera preview, but still camera preview working or not ? If it working there will be a battery and performance issues. Can you confirm that camera preview not working under the layout you added.

Comment: @Dulanga Yeah, you are right.. Please check edited answer.

Comment: No but thank you very much Umang your great, I ll try to do it another way

Comment: If my answer helped you in anyway, please upvote it.. Thanks.